# Pages document saved in MS Word format is not well-formatted?

Tags: pages, iwork

I use pages but most of my friends/clients don't. If I save a Pages document in MS Word format and send it over to them, most of them see it all garbled.

Even when I open the doc file in Pages, it is messed up (text over graphics and so on). So to fix this, I open the doc in Pages, fix every thing and save it again (which is a very cumbersome process)

Is there any setting which we can use to ensure this doesn't happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without more concrete examples of "all garbled." But the answer is probably "no, there's no one setting to make everything work out the way you want."

Since the two programs are very different, it's challenging to get a one-to-one correspondence of document formats when you export out of Pages to .doc format.

In general, my advice is that your exported .doc files will look closer to your Pages documents if you use Pages' Word Processing mode, rather than its Page Layout mode.

Mixing images with text, especially in a page layout fashion (with text wrapped around images and the like), is especially problematic, since the .doc format isn't as well suited as Pages for that sort of thing.

If you want your associates to see just what you are creating, you are probably better off to send them a PDF from Pages than to try to use .doc format. If they need to make changes/edits/comments to your work, I would suggest that you send them the initial text (without inline images) in RTF, then incorporate their changes into your Pages document by hand, then produce your final document in Pages and end up as PDF.